# Is there an interface type I can use in an interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to pass an object to a react component as well as the object's interface. Here's an example of an interface I want to use:

```
interface TableProps {
  ObjectProps: Interface (doesn't work);
  objects: Array<ObjectProps>;
}
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Are you trying to use [*generics*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), `interface TableProps<T> { objects: T[] }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, You are trying to define an interface name ObjectProps and also use it in another interface.

If thats the scenario, Define the ObjectProps separately as a type or an interface. And then call ObjectProps TableProps interface.

**Update**

In my understanding, its not possible to change **child component's** type from **parent component** because for a better understanding we can say,  type of props in child component is its private property which can not be defined by the parent.

But still what you can do is, define multiple types with "?" like bellow:

```
type ObjectProps= ...you type here

interface TableProps{
     objects1?: Array<ObjectProps>;
     objects2?: Array<ObjectProps>;
}
```

In this case, you can pass any of the object1 or object 2 from parent component to the child without error. But not any of them is mandatory.

Comment: The problem with that is I'm using React components, passing the object as props from a parent. The interface would change depending on how the component is called.